# Beginner R: Using Incident Data, Create a Series of New Dataframes with Sums of Categorical Variables

Tags: r

I have a set of incident data following the rough format:

```
Incident #   Date   Year   State   Criminal Offense   Location
```

155k incidents.  I want to create a new series of dataframes that group my ungrouped data (ie, the opposite of the first step in this link: http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/descriptive.html).  I want dataframes with each year/each state totals of each categorical count for each of the last 2 columns above, "offense" and "location" (but there would only ever be one row for each year-state combination)  So it would be 2 separate dataframes:

```
Year   State   Sum of Criminal Offense 1   Sum of Criminal Offense 2   Sum of Crim 3
```

and

```
Year   State   Sum of Location 1   Sum of Location 2   Sum of Location 3
```

The goal was to do comparisons of incident counts by state over time, or time-series predictions for total incidents of a certain crime type in a certain state.  Could I do this just as easily from ungrouped data?  Is there a resource or some brief rules for which analyses/predictive approaches work best/most practically for grouped versus ungrouped data?

Comment: I've seen a lot of resources on tapply, but none of them seem quite the same as this...I know how to make a table, but I want (ideally in only a couple lines of code) to make a dataframe that computes 50 * 20 * 12 tables, and only outputs a single value to each entry.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using `table` to count the entities and `reshape` to put it into the desired form.

Fake data:

```
d <- data.frame(Incident=1:4, Year=c(1,1,2,2), State=c('AL','MN','AL','MN'),Offense=c(1,1,1,2),Location=c(1,2,2,2))
d
##   Incident Year State Offense Location
## 1        1    1    AL       1        1
## 2        2    1    MN       1        2
## 3        3    2    AL       1        2
## 4        4    2    MN       2        2
```

Locations:

```
dl <- as.data.frame(xtabs(~Year+State+Location, data=d))
# dl <- as.data.frame(table(Year=d$Year, State=d$State, Location=d$Location))

reshape(dl, direction='wide', timevar='Location', idvar=c('Year', 'State'))
##   Year State Freq.1 Freq.2
## 1    1    AL      1      0
## 2    2    AL      0      1
## 3    1    MN      0      1
## 4    2    MN      0      1
```

Offenses:

```
do <- as.data.frame(xtabs(~Year+State+Offense, data=d))
# do <- as.data.frame(table(Year=d$Year, State=d$State, Offense=d$Offense))

reshape(do, direction='wide', timevar='Offense', idvar=c('Year', 'State'))
##   Year State Freq.1 Freq.2
## 1    1    AL      1      0
## 2    2    AL      1      0
## 3    1    MN      1      0
## 4    2    MN      0      1
```

Comment: What if there are additional values tied to each year/state combination?  Like population and unemployment rate.  The syntax would just be to include those in the "idvar" part of reshape?  There is only 1 population and unemployment rate value for each year/state combination (of which there is only one as well).

Comment: Suggestion: using `xtabs` instead of `table`, so you have, for example: `do <- xtabs(~ Year + State + Offense, d)`

Comment: I used xtabs without error, but then when trying to reshape, it perpetually asks for more arguments.

Comment: Indeed, I was able to get Mr. Lundberg's way to work without trouble, and considering the data is 600 x 155000 cells and my laptop is crappy, it was instantaneous...does using xtabs skip the need for the reshape step?

Comment: @user3392615 `xtabs` is a formula interface to `table`.  You still need to pass to `as.data.frame` to get the output in the form suitable for `reshape`.  I'll edit and add the code using `xtabs`.

Comment: You can't effectively deal with that many fields.  You should somehow reduce the scope of the problem.

Comment: I'm only adding two columns...unemployment rate and population, for each state/year combination.  But I guess the total cells > 2^31 is the problem?...this may be a question for Cross-Validated as it makes more sense to first conceptualize the task correctly given the data format.

Comment: Another idea: could I do it with just the year/state/categoricalvariable, and then just append the corresponding unemployment rate/population to the final reformatted frequency table?  Because the final table post-reshape is much smaller than the initial xtabs table?

Comment: And a second component of that question would be, how would I append the appropriate/corresponding field for unemployment rate/population to the final reshaped table?  I use a crude method of vectorization for pulling in the correct data, which may be a starting point: 

     trainvec=(Year<2007)
     HCtrain=StateUnemp[trainvec,]
     HCtest=StateUnemp[!trainvec,]

Comment: Hmm so adding in Population and Unemployment rate with the above syntax (I can only do one or the other given memory constraints) doesn't work.  The State and Year match correctly, one row only for each state/year combination, but the unemployment rate field is always zero??  And now the frequencies are messed up?  So, best solution would be to use your method for year/state + categorical frequency, and then append the other data by matching year/state combination afterwards.  But, I don't understand why I can't just add other variables to xtabs?